# How do I add a Windows Phone 7 Pin To Start command within my app to jump directly to some page?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to offer a Pin to Start menu command when the user presses and holds on certain sections within my Windows Phone 7 app, as utilized within many other apps.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not available in the current version of the operating system, and framework for third party application developers. Clearly the capability is there because various pre-installed applications (Office, Maps, etc) do this, but it's not available to developers like you and me.

Comment: this does this - http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/a4d7d142-2dbe-42d8-a8d0-0a2986ba868e

Answer (score 2):

now be done from the upgrade to handle with silverlight toolkit, this is the code you need to use for the button and assign it only created the animated tile, you can add more properties these are the ones I use.

```
private void CreateLiveTile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var newTile = new StandardTileData()
    {
        Title = "Draw Anime",
        BackgroundImage = new Uri("icon2.png", UriKind.Relative),
        BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("icon1.png", UriKind.Relative),
        Count = 42,

    };

    ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative), newTile);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could think about a workaround in your app, let user to decide which page will be his start page, pin app from menu, and on app start navigate to page user decided to become his start page.

It's really sad that we can't pin any page to Start Screen directly...