# How to pin one of my application pages to Home page - Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, msdn

There has already been a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852154/how-do-i-add-a-windows-phone-7-pin-to-start-command-within-my-app-to-jump-direct) asked about this on SOF 1.5 years and I want to ask it again.

Is it possible to pin a particular page within my application to home page so that when the user clicks it, it goes there. I see [this](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/a4d7d142-2dbe-42d8-a8d0-0a2986ba868e) application is indeed doing exactly that (although its published by Microsoft). But after an exhaustive search online and for msdn docs I cannot find a similar implementation.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

[How to: Create, Delete, and Update Tiles for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202979%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Specifically, look at the section:  **Implementing the SecondaryTile Page** as this covers the functionality you're looking for.

Happy Coding!